# How to get ManyToMany Field values in with selecte_related

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I'm new to django. I'm using a ManyToMany field in my Profile model with Membership Model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    membership = models.ManyToManyField(MemberShip, null=True)
```

What I want to do is I want to get all the users who has specific membership(from membership model)

[image]

For example I want the list of all the users who has the Red Membership. I researched and found out that `select_related()` or `prefetch_related` can help in some way. but I can't understand how can I use these methods to get what I want.

I've tried this:

```
user_memberships_all = Profile.objects.all()
for m in user_memberships_all:
    affiliate_with_membership = m.membership.select_related('user').all()
```

but I get an error saying `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'user'.`
if there is another of achieving this. can you please help with that. Thank You.

Comment: Where do you want to list these users?

Comment: in a view. I'm updating the question with what I've tried so far.

Comment: @IainShelvington can you take a look now.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a many to one relationship? If all your fetching is membership rank?

Answer (score 0):

To get all Users related to a specific MemberShip you can follow the OneToOneField backwards and then filter on the ManyToManyField

```
# Filtering on a "name" attribute of MemberShip

User.objects.filter(profile__membership__name='red')

# Using a MemberShip instance

red_membership = MemberShip.objects.get(name='red')
User.objects.filter(profile__membership=red_membership)
```